# How can I count the number of items in inventory available on any given day?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains records for items that are available. Each of the records contains a field for the date it was added to the inventory, the date it was removed from inventory (otherwise NULL) and a unique serial number (separate from the primary key). There are also other fields giving metadata about the item, like brand, model, height, weight, etc.

Using that table I want to come up with a new table that tells me item availability for every day, from the first item availability date until present, for all items. , ie I want to convert the item availability data from a sparse to dense representation.

I know this involves doing a join to a table of dates, but I don’t know how to do that, or even how to describe more formally what I am trying to do. My mental model for this would be to create an X rows by Y columns, with each row a given serial number and column for date, but I don’t know how to do this in sql and I think it will make unmanageable large tables. I think a better way would be to have a long narrow table, with one column for date and another for serial number and a third indicating it’s presence or absence. But I don’t know if this is feasible at all.

Currently I am trying to accomplish this in MySQL, but I can do it either in Postgres or MS Sql/SQL Server if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe start by posting the structure of your existing table plus some sample data from that table. Then post what data should be in the new table based on that sample data.

Comment: Also please only tag one DBMS, it just annoys people when you spam tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understand correctly this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=12f0d719ce5cb1f790790cff70a50d47) does do what you want:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates AS(
    SELECT 
      min(dateadded) AS d, 
      0 as x
    FROM items
    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD(d,INTERVAL 1 DAY),x+1
    FROM dates 
    WHERE d<=(SELECT MAX(dateadded) FROM items)
)
SELECT 
   d,
   serialnumber
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN items ON d BETWEEN items.dateadded 
                         AND COALESCE(items.dateremoved,'2099-12-31')
ORDER BY 1,2
```

- The `dates` part is created containing all available dates, from the first `dateadded` to the last `dateadded`+1.
- The query will only select all available serialnumbers per date.

It should not be hard to change this to add also a column `available` to show if the serialnumber is available, or not, but this is left as an exercise to the reader .